# Is there any way to prevent Rails autocleaning class variables when testing emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I testing a Rails application that sends emails in some situations. It's an API.

For the testing, I'm using the Airborne gem, which makes API testing pretty easy. All went correct except when I had to test the email deliveries. I tried the following:

```
it "blah" do
  //Code that makes my API send an email
  puts ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.inspect
end
```

But `deliveries` array is always empty. I also tried with `Emails.deliveries.inspect`. Emails is my custom Mailer that inherits `ActionMailer::Base`.

I ended reading the API documentation of ActionMailer and met the interceptor concept. Interceptors doesn't work in `:test` delivery method so I switched to `:smtp`. In fact, the emails are being sent correctly, but I can not access them on the tests to make expectations.

My interceptor code is this right now

```
initializers/email_interceptor.rb

class EmailInterceptor

  @@msgs = []    

  def self.delivering_email(message)
    puts message
    //Rails.logger.debug "Email being sent: " + message.to_s
    @@msgs << message
    Rails.logger.debug "Actual messages array: #{@@msgs}"
  end

  def self.msgs
    @@msgs
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(EmailInterceptor)
```

All OK. The debug messages print the array being populated correctly. But the variable is cleaned before my test statement is executed.
EDIT: The code above is executed when I run my test suite. But the variable is empty accessed from the test itself.

```
//test code
puts EmailInterceptor.msgs.inspect
=> []
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Did you mean `Rails.logger.debug "Actual messages array: #{@@msgs}"`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false` in your test.rb config. It seems like you should really be using `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test` since this will allow `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` to be populated, which makes for easier and more reliable testing. Do you really need interceptors for your tests?

Comment: I don't have `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false` in my `test.rb` environment file. In fact, I also tried putting that value to true explicitly and `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` is also empty when accessed from the `it` block of the test.

Comment: Ok, curious as to why you need `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` in tests, though. Why not just use `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test`?

Comment: I use `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` because I ended up trying to solve my problem with Interceptors. If the value is set to `:test` the emails aren't being really delivered and the interceptor code is not called.